# Running my JSP page on Tomcat in Eclipse. Where is the problem?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets, contextpath

I'm trying to run my login.jsp on Tomcat in Eclipse and get a 404 error. I excluded /WEB-INF from the url and got a different result! The browser loaded a line of code in my LoginServlet: Served at: /FirstDynamicWebProject", which is the parent folder for login.jsp.  So it seems like Tomcat is executing my project, but I can't figure out what the problem might be then.

Comment: Where is your JSP file, and are any URIs mapped for it in the `web.xml`?

Comment: Files in the `/WEB-INF` directory are not (directly) accessing from the web. It's a security feature.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.